React Native Linear Gradient problem importing
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, Image, TouchableOpacity, LinearGradient} from 'react-native';
const bgImage = require('./img/car.gif');

export default function App() {
  return (
    <LinearGradient style={styles.container}>

        colors={['rgb(32, 38, 57)', 'rgb(63, 76, 119)']}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
        style={styles.gradient}
        locations={[0.2, 0.6, 0.8]}

      <Text style={styles.title}>JDM LEGENDS</Text>
      <Image source = {bgImage} style={styles.image}>
      </Image>
      <Text style={styles.title2}>Welcome Car Enthusiast!  </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title3}>This Application is intended for Car lovers specifically the JDM legends. This is a Free Access Application Open for every car enthusiast out there!  </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />

      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            // handle onPress
          }}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>GET CAR-STED</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </LinearGradient>
    
  );
}

Please help.

use react-native-linear-gradient library.
